# JavaScript - Receiving NAN when trying to divide a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please checkout my code:

```
var BasicPrice = NewPrice.substring(0, NewPrice.indexOf('лв.'));
var HalfPrice = (Number.BasicPrice)/2;
alert(HalfPrice);
```

I receive an output `NaN`, but when i do `alert(BasicPrice);` i receive an output like `83.25` which is a correct number but why it can not divide it properly ?

Where is my mistake, how i can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Number.BasicPrice is looking up the BasicPrice property of the Number object, which is undefined most probably.

Comment: Are you sure that BasicPrice is of the type Number? try: `console.log(typeof(BasicPrice))` and look, if BasicPrice is actually of the type 'number'.

Comment: You're defining ```BasicPrice``` with a ```var``` how could it possibly now be a property of ```Number```. Also ```substring``` returns a string, not a number and wrapping it in ```()``` will evaluate it but not transform it into a number. Strings cannot be divided.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting `Number.BasicPrice` to cast `BasicPrice` to a number; that's not how Javascript does it. See the answers for how to fix that, but I think that's where the confusion is coming from

Answer (score 4):

You can just preceed the expression by a plus sign (`+`) to convert it to numeric type

```
var BasicPrice = +NewPrice.substring(0, NewPrice.indexOf('лв.'));
var HalfPrice = BasicPrice/2;
alert(HalfPrice);
```

Comment: I like this way. Good to note that in case of an empty string the value would be 0

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that BasicPrice is of the type Number?

try: `console.log(typeof(BasicPrice))` and look, if BasicPrice is actually of the type 'number'. If not, you may just convert it from (I guess) string to number by with:

```
var numInstance = parseFloat(BasicPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking from your code, you are using this `(Number.BasicPrice)` which I believe is wrong. It is looking for the `BasicPrice` property of `Number`.

```
   var BasicPrice = NewPrice.substring(0, NewPrice.indexOf('лв.'));
   var HalfPrice = parseFloat(BasicPrice)/2;
```

Comment: The ```()``` around ```parseFloat``` are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do validations on arithmetic operations especially with variables where typeof is unknown, or loosely typed languages. Here is a reference to documentation on [Number from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). Also, have a look at [javascript styleguide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) from Google around variable naming conventions. ie. camelCase

```
var BasicPrice = NewPrice.substring(0, NewPrice.indexOf('лв.'));

// because its substring(), conversion may require
// ie. isInteger(), is typeOf(x) === 'number', parseInt(string)

var HalfPrice = (Number.BasicPrice)/2;
alert(HalfPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any conversion. Also you are trying to access BasicPrice as a property of Number which is syntactically wrong.

Try this-

```
var BasicPrice = NewPrice.substring(0, NewPrice.indexOf('лв.'));
var HalfPrice = BasicPrice/2;
alert(HalfPrice);
```